# Unable to fetch lookup field values using REST api

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I am using REST api to fetch data from a SharePoint list.

I am able to get the lookup fields data using this query:
`requestUri = "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Data')/items?$select=ID,Title,Department/Title&$expand=Department`.

However when I use this query `requestUri = "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Data')/items(6)"` or this query `requestUri = "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('Data')/items?$select=ID,Title,Department/Title&$expand=Department&$filter=ID eq 6"` I am not getting the data from the lookup fields.

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was found.

Figured out that I was fetching an item for which all the lookup fields were blank.

I fetched another item, and data was returned as expected.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information, yes, if lookup fields were blank, it will return values.
You can accept as answer so that it could help others in the forum.

Answer (score 1):

I tested with the endpoint, it works:

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items(1)?$select=ID,Title,Department/Title&$expand=Department
```

[image]

Compared the url with yours in original question, only append web behind /_api, it should be working.